# Hide / Unhide application when connect / disconnect USB BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-task

My application only have `MainActivity` with a `ImageView`.

`BroadcastReceiver` works. The Toast Message is displayed When I connect USB.

Now, I need start my application minimized and show the application only the USB cable was connected.

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcast_reciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("usb_detect")) {
            Toast.makeText(arg0,"Atenção!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            //startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER));
        }
    }
};
```

Manifest is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa3Pe.jpg

Comment: Please specifically ask what you are looking for help with. Is the question "How do I start my application minimized and show the application only the USB cable is connected"? Also, please provide samples of what you have tried already.

Comment: I have a button to hide the application (moveTaskToBack(true)). I need open the application again when the USB connection was received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring your application to the foreground, add the following to `onReceive()`:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().
    getLaunchIntentForPackage("your.package.name");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

This will not start a new `Activity`, it will simply bring the existing task containing your application to the foreground in whatever state it was in when it got moved to the background.

Also, remove the call to `finish()` from your `BroadcastReceiver`. `finish()` is only used on an `Activity`.

Comment: Not work. Only the Toast is show.
            if (action.equals("usb_detect")) {
                Toast.makeText(arg0,"Atenção!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().
                        getLaunchIntentForPackage("br.com.compex.testeimageviewgif");
                startActivity(launchIntent);

Comment: Please add your manifest to your question. Edit the question and paste in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks David. I put a picture. Is visible to you?

Comment: Try changing `startActivity()` to `arg0.getApplicationContext().startActivity()` instead. If that doesn't work please add your current code to your question.